# How to remap a combination of buttons clicks to run a script

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sxhkd

I'm running BSPWM as my tiling window manager, and SXHKD as my mapping tool.
And i want to kill the current window when i click a combination of:

`button1 + button1 + button3` (double left click + right click).

I tried adding this to my sxhkd config:

```bsh
button1 + button1 + button3
  ./some_script.sh
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
I wonder if there is another solution, using other tools may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do chords, they are separated by semicolons like this:

```
button1; button1; button2
            
         ./some_script.sh
```

from the sxhkd man page:

When multiple chords are separated by
semicolons, the hotkey is a chord chain: the
command will only be executed after receiving
each chord of the chain in consecutive order.

The colon character can be used instead of the
semicolon to indicate that the chord chain
shall not be aborted when the chain tail is
reached.